TypeScript interface with array destructuring
I want to make types for functions like these (simplified example):
function asyncStore(initialValue) {
   return {
      ...createStore(initialValue),
      get 0() {
        return this
      },
      1: createStore('pending'),
      [Symbol.iterator]: function *() {
        yield this[0]
        yield this[1]
      }
   }
}

function createSomeEnhancedStore(sourceStore) {
  return {
    ...sourceStore,
    someEnhanceMethod() { /* ... */ }
  }
}

const [value, status] = createSomeEnhancedStore(asyncStore(0))

My types draft:
/* Some deps */
interface Store<T> {
  value: T
}

type AnyStore = Store<any>

function createStore<T>(initialValue: T): Store<T> {
  return { value: initialValue }
}

/* Types for function */
interface AsyncStore<T> extends Store<T> {
  0: this,
  1: Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>
}

function asyncStore<T>(initialValue: T): AsyncStore<T> {
   return {
      ...createStore(initialValue),
      get 0() {
        return this
      },
      1: createStore('pending'),
      [Symbol.iterator]: function *() {
        yield this[0]
        yield this[1]
      }
   }
}

function createSomeEnhancedStore<T extends AnyStore>(sourceStore: T): T & { someEnhanceMethod(): void } {
  return {
    ...sourceStore,
    someEnhanceMethod() { /* ... */ }
  }
}

const [value, status] = createSomeEnhancedStore(asyncStore(0))

Problem:
this works:
const enhancedStore = createSomeEnhancedStore(asyncStore(0))

enhancedStore.someEnhanceMethod() // types ok
enhancedStore[0].someEnhanceMethod() // types ok

this not:
const [value, status] = enhancedStore // types error

because of AsyncStore interface should contain Symbol.iterator property types, but how it should be described?
interface AsyncStore<T> extends Store<T> {
  0: this,
  1: Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>
  [Symbol.iterator]: Iterator<this | Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>>
}

will not work:
const [value, status] = enhancedStore

value and status are this | Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>
but expected types are this for value and Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'> for status.
Please help me.

I think for destructuring you'd need a tuple type: type AsyncStore<T> = Store<T> & [0: this, 1: Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>]. However that means actually implementing an array, not just an iterable object with two index properties.

This is a missing feature, see ms/TS#42033. You cannot currently treat arbitrary iterators like tuples. For now you'll have to work around it by making an actual array subtype (and play games with having the array be actually implemented in an async/lazy way) or give up on this approach. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer or find a suitable duplication source. If not, what am I missing?

@Bergi @jcalz How I should make an actual array subtype?
type AsyncStore<T> = Store<T> & [this, Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>]
will not work because you can't use this in object types, it available only in interfaces

@dangreen Oops, [AsyncStore<T>, Store<…>] should work though.

@Bergi then enhancedStore.someEnhanceMethod will not defined in this case

We can extend Array interface in our interface:
interface AsyncStore<T> extends Store<T>, Array<AnyStore> {
  0: this
  1: Store<'pending' | 'fulfilled' | 'rejected'>
}
// ...
const [value, status] = createSomeEnhancedStore(asyncStore(0))
// const value: AsyncStore<number> & {
//    someEnhanceMethod(): void;
// }
// const state: Store<"pending" | "fulfilled" | "rejected">

